# How to add data to Elementor toggle widget

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am usingElementor Pro 3.13.2 and I have added a toggle widget to one of my pages.

[image]

[image]

The ID of the toggle is 'dlista' and is assigned through the 'Advanced' tab as a CSS ID.

[image]

Now, what I am trying to do, is to populate data from my plugin. I am not trying to edit the widget as such and I am also not trying to create my own widget.

I have data stored in a mysql table that I am fetching based on certain criteria. I have no issues fetching the data, but I am struggling to understand how I can populate the toggle widget with the data that I have fetched. Each row from the mysql query as a separate toggle entry.

Anyone that could provide an example or help me achieve this? I just can't figure it out..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_custom_items_to_toggle_widget_elementor($items, $widget) {
    
    if ('toggle' === $widget->get_name()) {
        
        $new_items = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Item 1',
                'content' => 'Item 1 content',
                'active' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Item 2',
                'content' => 'Item 2 content',
                'active' => false,
            ),
            
        );

        $items = array_merge($items, $new_items);
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter('elementor/widget/toggle/section_items', 'add_custom_items_to_toggle_widget_elementor', 10, 2);
```

You can add this to your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my issue. I am not after creating a shortcode, that I already have. I would like to understand how to add items to an existing widget from Elementor (the toggle widget). Thank you

Comment: @Antonios edit the code in above snippet.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much! Is it possible to also user $widget->get_id() to check the id of the specific toggle widget?

Could you also refer me to the link in the docs where you could find this information? I still struggle to find around :\

Thank you so much, will try this asap and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_custom_items_to_toggle_widget_elementor($items, $widget) {
    
    if ('toggle' === $widget->get_name() && 'toggle-widget-id-here' === $widget->get_id()) {
        
        $new_items = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Item 1',
                'content' => 'Item 1 content',
                'active' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Item 2',
                'content' => 'Item 2 content',
                'active' => false,
            ),
            // Add more items as needed
        );

        // Merge the new items with the existing ones
        $items = array_merge($items, $new_items);
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter('elementor/widget/toggle/section_items', 'add_custom_items_to_toggle_widget_elementor', 10, 2);
```

Try this code.

Use below code for get widget id.
$widget_id = $widget->get_id();

Comment: I am not sure it is working :\ I've changed the code just to see if the function is called, but it isn't:

`function toggleAdd($items, $widget) {
 echo '<script>console.log("' . $widget->get_id() . ' : ' . $widget->get_name() . '");</script>';
 return $items;
}
add_filter('elementor/widget/toggle/section_items', 'toggleAdd', 10, 2);`

Comment: Following are the reasons why your code not working.

Ensure that the add_filter function is executed after the Elementor plugin has been loaded. Placing it in the theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin file should work.

Make sure the toggleAdd function is defined and accessible when the add_filter function is executed.

Comment: The third parameter of add_filter specifies the priority of the callback function. If there are other functions hooked to the same filter, check if any of them modify the $items array and if their priority might conflict with your toggleAdd function. You could try increasing the priority value (e.g., from 10 to a higher number) to ensure it runs after other filter functions.

Comment: Verify that the $widget parameter passed to the toggleAdd function is indeed an instance of the expected object with the get_id() and get_name() methods. You might need to review the code responsible for invoking the filter hook and ensure the correct object is passed as an argument.

Check if there are any JavaScript errors occurring in the browser's console. Make sure the code inside the <script> tag is being executed by inspecting the page source or using developer tools.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/bQqDec2QCF-I - see this screenshot. You can give widget id like this.

Comment: Hi again,

I have placed this code block inside my themes functions.php. I have also placed the add_filter function after the toggleAdd function.

I also tried to raise the priority of the callback function. To ensure the correct $widget is catched, I have removed all checks and just try to pass the ID of whatever object is catched to the console using JS. But nothing is being passed, that is the problem. I load a page with toggle elements but it is like the function is not executed at all.

Comment: You dont need to manage the data with php. You can fill the data on widget from backend.

Comment: Hello, I have followed your instructions but didn't manage to solve this. I have a table in MySQL where I store certain data. I want to fetch the data based on certain criteria and load the results to a toggle widget, each row from mysql as separate toggle item.

Comment: I have now tried this countless of times, not sure what I am doing wrong. I copied your code and added it to the functions.php doc of my theme. This code is generated: ```<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d71e9a3 elementor-widget elementor-widget-toggle" data-id="d71e9a3" data-element_type="widget" id="compslist" data-widget_type="toggle. Default">```. I have tried with 'compslist' as ID, I have tried with 'd71e9a3' as ID. Not sure what I am doing wrong... Here is a test page I created: https://abkollen.se/toggle-testing/